# Openshift + Imagetag not found

Tags: openshift

I have application deployed in openshift, I have been multiple WAR deployment till date. But today when I try to deploy a new war into openshift 3, I got below error.

> The ImageStreamTag "jboss-webserver31-tomcat8-openshift:latest" is
>   invalid: from: Error resolving ImageStreamTag
>   jboss-webserver31-tomcat8-openshift:latest in namespace openshift:
>   unable to find latest tagged image

It seems this image has been deleted if so then how could I deploy on same pod?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this problem.

You need to change the image name of the build.

1. Click on Build
2. Click on Service
3. Click on Action Dropdown box -> Click on Edit menu
4. Change version of "Build From" image. In my case, build from Tomcat with latest tag. but now as latest tag is no more hence I have selected 1.1 and it works again.

Happy Hunting.